# HTML form calls a PHP page that returns an attachment; how do I return "control" to the HTML page?

Tags: php, html

All,

I have an HTML page that contains a form.

When the user completes the form and clicks "Submit" - the form posts the user's inputs to a PHP page.

That PHP page processes the inputs and returns the user's results **as an attachment**.

So far - everything works OK - the user clicks "Submit", the browser's progress bar starts to "spin", and after a few seconds, the attachment is downloaded.

However, in the browser - the user is still on the form page. That's OK with me.

So - here's my question. Ideally, when the user clicks "Submit" - I would like to update the form page to indicate that the "process" is in progress. E.g.,

- disable the submit button to prevent redundant clicks
- display a "downloading" message and a "spinner"-type graphic

Then, when the download is complete - I'd like to capture that event so that I could re-enable the submit button and remove the downloading message.

Is this possible?

Or - is my initial set-up just wrong? Is there a better way to do this? (That is - have a form that calls a PHP page, have the PHP page return an attachment, and then return control to the calling page?)

Thanks in advance for your advice and insight!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use javascript to open up the download in a new window. So don't return the download in the POST request, simply let the page reload and put some javascript on the page that will open up a new window that will call your PHP script that will download the file.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure there would be any event regarding the downloading/streaming files via http (consider that it happens totally on the server side), however, if I were you I would redirect the form to the download page and then after web server starts streaming the file to the client's browser, I would redirect back to the form page again.

You can achieve that both via PHP and Javascript. :)

Answer (score 1):

In order to get this kind of functionality (disabling submit button, showing a spinner or progress bar) you will need to use some JavaScript.  I would recommend the JQuery Ajax Form plugin: http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/.

The tricky part with using JS and AJAX is that it will be hard to have the user download the file as an attachment.

To use purely HTML and PHP I would recommend re-directing to another page on submit, displaying some message (..."processing"...) and then redirecting back to the form page where the page will load, prompt for the download, and then show the form again.

Answer (score 1):

A graceful way to handle this , might be through ajax.

a) On you final page when you press "Submit" button , you post an ajax request to

1. build the document dynamically and or generate link to download
   document
2. Return the download link in ajax response

b) On ajax response , you trigger the download link e.g

```
 //jquery code     
$.ajax ({...
        success:function(resp){
            window.open(resp.FILE);
            // to the rest of work here 
            // e.g enable disable submit button 
        })
```